# Unable to connect to the controller on 'MachineName:6901'. Cannot communicate with the Controller due to version mismatch

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

We are using "TFS 2012 Update3", "Visual Studio 2012 Premium Update4" and "TFS Test Agent and Controller 2012 Update4", I have installed TFS Controller, Agent and VS 2012 premium on same machine and TFS server is on another server machine. I am getting "Unable to connect to the controller on 'MachineName:6901'. Cannot communicate with the Controller due to version mismatch" error.

Answer (score 2):

Why would your build client, be in front of its server version?

I would downgrade your build client to update 3 (same version as TFS Server).

Visual studio is ok to be upgraded, without affecting TFS build.

Comment: Or check firewall policies 

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and restarted the box which magically fixed things. There was nothing to indicate I needed to do this.